# Its possible to cast an Collections.synchronizedList() from object read from file?

Tags: java, list, exception, collections, synchronization

I want to read a `Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList<>())` from a file where I saved that list before (It's that even possible?). And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at RMIServerImpl.loadAuctions(RMIServerImpl.java:247)
    at RMIServerImpl.rmiStart(RMIServerImpl.java:293)
    at RMIServerImpl.main(RMIServerImpl.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

My code:

```
private List<User> users;

public RMIServerImpl() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
    super();
    auctions = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()); 
}
public void saveAuctions(){
    ObjectFile file = new ObjectFile();
    try {
        file.openWrite("auctions");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem opening auctions file(WRITE MODE).");
    }
    try {
        file.writeObject(this.auctions);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem saving auctions");
    }
    try {
        file.closeWrite();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem close auctions file(WRITE MODE).");
    }
}
public void loadAuctions(){
    ObjectFile file = new ObjectFile();
    try {
        file.openRead("auctions");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem opening auctions file(READ MODE)(No auctions found)");
    }

    try {
        this.auctions= (ArrayList<Auction>) file.readObject();//PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem loading auctions");
    }

    try {
        file.closeRead();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem closing auctions file(READ MODE)");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collections.synchronizedList` doesn't return ArrayList, it returns list which may wrap it, but it is not ArrayList itself, nor extends it.

Comment: How is your file that are you reading ?

Comment: It's an object file, where I save my auctions list.

Comment: auctions is defined as: `private List<Auction> auctions`;

Comment: Have you tried casting it to `(List<Action>)` instead of `(ArrayList<Auction>)`?

Comment: Thanks, solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

casting it to (List) instead of (ArrayList) solved it